# Is there an error in my work book? (Double integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Hello it is my first post here!

I have integral
$$
\iint\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy
$$
over the area bounded by $y=x$, $2y=x^2$.

I tried to draw the area and it seemed like a pretty straightforward integral. Integrating by $\mathrm dx$, I have that $x\in[0,2]$, $y \in [\frac{x^2}{2}, x]$.

The integral then is:

$$\int_0^2 \int_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^x \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$  (swapped the integrals because I can't integrate by dx first since it's in a boundary) which evaluates to $2 - \frac{\pi}{2}$. However my workbook says that the solution is $\ln{2}$. Is there an error?

Comment: Your working seems correct. Book answer seems wrong to me.

Comment: I also think your book gave you answer for $\displaystyle \int_0^2 \int_{x^2/2}^x \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \ dy \ dx$. See the typo in numerator.

Comment: And really well done for the first post, including mathjax!

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for answering! It's just appropriate to learn the language used here!

Comment: Btw you could have set up the integral in the $dx \ dy$ order as well.

Comment: But I'd still have to integrate by dy first, right? I've been taught that if I have $x$ in the boundary, we can't integrate by $dx$ first. Same applies for $y$ and $dy$

Comment: No you can integrate wrt $dx$ first. Note that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} = 1 - \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Switching the order is a matter of changing the definition of the boundaries so that $x$ is considered in terms of $y$ and $y$ has a fixed interval, namely $y\in [0,2], x\in[y,\sqrt{2y}]$...

Answer (score 1):

I verify that your calculation of the iterated integral is correct:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{2} \int_{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}^{x} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} d y d x 
=\int_{0}^{2} x\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) d x =\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi+2=2-\frac\pi2
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the second integral, one can use integration by parts.

> ...because I can't integrate by dx first since it's in a boundary

It is worth knowing that the region that you are integrating on can be also written as
$$
D=\{(x,y): 0\le y\le 2\;, y\le x\le \sqrt{2y}\}
$$
which gives you the iterated integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{2} \int_{y}^{\sqrt{2 y}} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} d x d y
$$

So in principle, you *can* integrate with respect to $x$ first.

---

[image]